# BUILD FAILED: Cannot find an environment variable

Tags: java, linux, apache, ant, jar

I'm trying to build the TINOS/RINA project from https://github.com/PouzinSociety/tinos/tree/development
on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi Debian).

Its instructions are to issue `ant jar` in the build directory, but when I do so I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/tinos/projects/rina/build-rina/build.xml:34: Cannot find /opt/tinos/projects/rina/build-rina/${env.TINOS_HOME}/projects/spring-build/tinos/package-top-level.xml imported from /opt/tinos/projects/rina/build-rina/build.xml
```

So obviously there's an environment variable I'm missing somewhere, but is it a Linux environment variable, or some sort of Java or Apache/ANT variable?  Where do I set it?

I tried `set TINOS_HOME=/opt/tinos/` from command line, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid and never performed "export TINOS_HOME"  -- that's what fixed it (bash shell)